# Listing Processes if Any Process Exist Java

Tags: java, gwt, ftp

I'm developing a deployment project. I have an user interface for it and I binded interface with server via RPC Callback. I've used SmartGWT for interface.

My project simply downloads war file from a path, and deploys it to the server. Also I have a timer checks for updated version every 24 hours. 
My problem is that, How can I prevent my program to run twice at same time?
Firstly I though about disabling the "execute" button from interface, but this doesn't work properly if user refreshes page, or timer and user process works at same time. Then I though about using Singleton Pattern to solve this. Assuming that my FTP class called, ftp.DownloadFile method will start a long running download process. How can I determine if download process, or other processes are running? How can I list the requests from user while I already have a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginnig of the downloading process you need to store some sign on the server side (for example boolean flag, `downloadInProgress=true`). Then after each page refresh get the value of this variable via RPC call and show / hide UI commponents according to it. As a storage for this variable you can use:

- Database
- Server side session
- Everything statefull avalibale on server side...

Do not forget to assign false to `downloadInProgress` variable after downloading completed.